# Exception thrown trying to create a DB with SMO C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a database using SMO. I get this exception on the `Create()`:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Create failed for Database 'DataBase.t'. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'Resources\DataBase.t.mdf;' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean includeDbContext)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImplFinish(StringCollection createQuery, ScriptingPreferences sp)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database.Create()
>   at CustomSQLConnectionTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DatabaseCreationTest\DatabaseCreationTest\Program.cs:line 58

I tried may solutions and nothing worked. I ran the VS as administrator, the SQL Server Management Studio too, I set the permission to all the users. Also I tried running this query in the SSMS, with my directory, and it actually did work:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [bioenergiasIpad]    Script Date: 08/07/2012 17:01:19 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [test1] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'test1', 
  FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\test1.mdf', 
  SIZE = 70656KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'test1_log', 
  FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\test1_log.ldf', 
  SIZE = 164672KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

Source here

My code is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
string UserName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter password");
string Password = Console.ReadLine();

string connectionString = null;
SqlConnection cnn ;

Server server = new Server();
server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;

try
{
    connectionString = @"Data Source=" + server.Name + @"\Administrator" +
                            @"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Resources\DataBase." + UserName + ".mdf;" +
                             "Integrated Security=True;";

    Database database = new Database(server, "DataBase." + UserName);
    database.FileGroups.Add(new FileGroup(database, "PRIMARY"));

    DataFile dtPrimary = new DataFile(database.FileGroups["PRIMARY"], "PriValue", @"Resources\DataBase." + UserName + ".mdf;");
    dtPrimary.Size = 77.0 * 1024.0;
    dtPrimary.GrowthType = FileGrowthType.KB;
    dtPrimary.Growth = 1.0 * 1024.0;

    database.FileGroups["PRIMARY"].Files.Add(dtPrimary);

    LogFile logFile = new LogFile(database, "Log", @"Resources\DataBase." + UserName + ".ldf");
    logFile.Size = 7.0 * 1024.0;
    logFile.GrowthType = FileGrowthType.Percent;
    logFile.Growth = 10.0;

    database.LogFiles.Add(logFile);

    database.Create();
    database.Refresh();
}
```

I tried different connection strings.

Oh, and I am using SQL Server 2012.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930142/cant-create-a-database-in-sql-server-2012)

Comment: @Odrai I saw this one but it didn't work... every time I tried to change the file path it changed it back on its own, only the backup path didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are trying to create a file with full name `'Resources\DataBase.t.mdf;'`. Try to provide some correct name like you did it SQL example, like `'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\test1.mdf'` and it should be OK.

Comment: Tried to do it, but I still get the same error even if I try to put it into the bin folder (without using the path).

Comment: Yup, I put the file path in the name of the database.